# uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed my controller path like this.

[image]

and I have specified folder path exactly like this

```
class Admin::UserFoodController < Admin::ApplicationController

class Admin::UsersController < Admin::ApplicationController

class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

but, when I restart unicorn, I got error

```
/home/ubuntu/hid/admin/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
from /home/ubuntu/hid/admin/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
from /home/ubuntu/hid/admin/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
```

so I made dummy ApplicationController in controller folder, not in admin folder
error has gone.

I don't want to make dummy ApplicationController in controller folder. I wanna keep this folder structure.

what should I do?
help me plz...

Comment: why do you want to keep the `application_controller` inside the admin folder and not outside only?

Comment: is there any more of an error message? Do any other of your controllers (eg. those in the API folder) reference a base ApplicationController?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found.
because of devise gem.
I had to change some code in devise.rb(~/2.6.4/gems/lib/devise/devise.rb)

before = > "ApplicationController"
after => "Admin::ApplicationController"

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

inside app/controllers/admin/user_food_controller.rb, here is sample you can use

```
require_dependency "admin/application_controller"

module UserFoodController
  class UserFoodController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

by using require_dependency ensures that classes are loaded and unloaded in the correct manner.

the settings above "seems similar" with setting using rails engine and [here link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) in case you need to learn more